# Overriding listview item background in HTML- Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: html, listview, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, winjs

I have the following template deisgned to display a listview. But the items in the list assign a background color of black by default. I am not able to override their BG color property. I have experience in native WP developement using C#. But in HTML 5 and WinJS  am not able to figure out half the things about design.

HTML Code:

```
<div id="pivotScenario3" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.Pivot" data-win-options="{ selectedIndex: 4 }">

            <div id="listViewMenu" class="listviewpivotitem" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.PivotItem" data-win-options="{ 'header': 'SPORTS' }">
                <div data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView" data-win-options="{ itemDataSource: All.dataSource, layout: { type: WinJS.UI.ListLayout }, itemTemplate: menuItemTemplate, selectionMode: 'none' }"></div>
            </div>
```

Template code:

```
<div id="menuItemTemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
            <div class="menuItem">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <img data-win-bind="src: logo" alt="Databound image" class="logo" />
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            <div class="selectionmodeHitTarget win-interactive"></div>
                            <div class="sportNameRoot">
                                <h2 class="sportName" data-win-bind="innerHTML: sportName"></h2>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.menuItem {
display: -ms-grid;
-ms-grid-columns: 20px 1fr 60px;
-ms-grid-rows: auto auto auto;
background-color: transparent;}

.menuItem .selectionmodeHitTarget {
    /* So it is stacked on top of other grid elements */
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    -ms-grid-column: 1;
    -ms-grid-row: 1;
    -ms-grid-row-span: 3;
    width: 16px; /* reserve 4px gap between highlight and item edge */
    height: 100%;
    transition: background-color 250ms ease-out 250ms, visibility 0ms linear 500ms, transform cubic-bezier(0.17,0.79,0.215,1.0025) 250ms;
}

    .menuItem .selectionmodeHitTarget:active {
        transition: background-color ease-out 100ms; /* fade in fast */
        background-color: Highlight;
    }

    .menuItem .selectionmodeHitTarget:after {

        margin: 0 16px;
        width: 16px;
        height: 100%;
        content: '';
    }

.win-selectionmode .menuItem .selectionmodeHitTarget {
transform: translateX(-41px); /* delayed by transition */
visibility: hidden;}

.win-selectionmode .win-item {
overflow: visible;}
```

CSS for pivot n listview

```
.listviewpivotitem.win-pivot-item .win-pivot-item-content {
/* Stretch across the whole width of the screen so the whole thing is pannable.*/
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
width: 100%;}

.win-listview {
height: 100%;}

#pivotScenario3 .win-listview .win-container {
margin: 0;
padding: 5px 0 0 0;
background-color: transparent;}

#pivotScenario3 .win-listview.win-rtl .win-item {
margin: 0 0 0 20px;}

#pivotScenario3{
color:white;}
```

My need is that, i want to set any desired color as background color for listview items.

I know this is a lot of code to go through but my problem is too complicated. Haven't found a solution since a week. This is my last resort.

All help, suggestions and answers are appreciated!

Comment: With the DOM explorer, Try to find out, what classes are used to style the list view, Then over ride them inside your styles.If you feel they still don't work override with !important.Its not a good practice though.

Comment: Had to override the ui-dark-theme.css file.. works fine now. will post the answer soon!

Comment: But you cant change background color dynamically by changing just CSS

Comment: You can change the background color in ui-theme.css files.

Answer (score 0):

Bind color code with style property
like:
`<div data-win-bind="style.background:Color"></div>`
it will give you the expected result.
All the Best..!!